# Spaces within a set of tuples

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I want to have a set of tuples spaced with ":". I tried the following:

```
$\{1:1, 1:0, 0:1, 2:1, 1:2, 2:2\}$
```

but in the output, there is a space between the number and the colon. How can I get rid of that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

write it this way:

```
$\{1{:}1, 1{:}0, 0{:}1, 2{:}1, 1{:}2, 2{:}2\}$
```

or redefine the meaning of : if you do not need it otherwise in math mode

Comment: That is the correct answer, but it could have been made even better by pointing out that what happens here is that the colon in math mode is considered a relation, hence the space. While surrounding it with braces forces it to become an ordinary symbol. (Learn about mathcodes to understand this in more detail.) There is also the control sequence `\colon` which typesets a colon as a punctuation character, which yields a space after but not before it.